# Determining if the Maximize button is available

Tags: c#, winapi

Does anyone know where I can find an example of how to determine if the Maximize and/or Minimize buttons on a window are available and/or disabled?

The window will not be in the same process as my application.  I have the hWnd and I have tried using GetMenuItemInfo, but I can't find any good samples for how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
bool has_maximize_btn = (GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_MAXIMIZEBOX) != 0;
bool has_minimize_btn = (GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_MINIMIZEBOX) != 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

The Win32 API provides the [**GetTitleBarInfo** function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633513(VS.85).aspx) which returns a [**TITLEBARINFO** Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632608(VS.85).aspx):

```
typedef struct {
    DWORD cbSize;
    RECT rcTitleBar;
    DWORD rgstate[CCHILDREN_TITLEBAR+1];
} TITLEBARINFO, *PTITLEBARINFO, *LPTITLEBARINFO;
```

So you could check the `rgstate`: Pointer to an array that receives a DWORD value for each element of the title bar. The following are the title bar elements represented by the array.

```
Index Title Bar Element
----- --------------------
0     The title bar itself
1     Reserved.
2     Minimize button
3     Maximize button    <--------------
4     Help button
5     Close button
```

Each array element is a combination of one or more of the following values.

```
Value                    Meaning
-----                    -------------------------------------------
STATE_SYSTEM_FOCUSABLE   The element can accept the focus.
STATE_SYSTEM_INVISIBLE   The element is invisible.
STATE_SYSTEM_OFFSCREEN   The element has no visible representation.
STATE_SYSTEM_UNAVAILABLE The element is unavailable.  
STATE_SYSTEM_PRESSED     The element is in the pressed state.rgstate
```

Comment: Wow, I'm working with Win32, on and off, for what... 10 years, and I never heard of this function! :) Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [GetWindowInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633516(VS.85).aspx) function.

Test the [WINDOWINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632610(VS.85).aspx) structure's dwStyle field and see if the WS_MAXIMIZEBOX bit is on.

```
WINDOWINFO.dwStyle & WS_MAXIMIZEBOX != 0
```

Comment: You probably meant WS_MAXIMIZEBOX. WS_MAXIMIZE is a different thing.

Comment: Hm, Asher, isn't WS_MAXIMIZE used to indicate that you want to create a maximized window?

Comment: @splattne - I think that the TITLEBARINFO can be used to indicate that the maximize box is N/A (but visible). this occurs when the window is already maximized.