# Determine if window has close button (Or, why isn't GetTitleBarInfo working?)

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I'm trying to determine if a given window has a close button using the [GetTitleBarInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633513%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, as recommended in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/311410/300212). But when I call the function the return value for `rgstate[5]` - which should indicate the close button state - is always 0 and I don't understand why. Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Alternatively, if any one can suggest another method to get this information, that would be helpful as well. Thanks!

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern bool GetTitleBarInfo(IntPtr hwnd, ref TITLEBARINFO pti);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct TITLEBARINFO
{
    public int cbSize;
    public RECT rcTitleBar;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
    public int[] rgstate;
}

IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();
TITLEBARINFO titleBarInfo = new TITLEBARINFO();
titleBarInfo.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(titleBarInfo);

if (!GetTitleBarInfo(handle, ref titleBarInfo))
    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

// titleBarInfo.rgstate[5] is always 0 here. Why?
```

**Edit:** Just to be clear, according to MSDN the return value should be a combination of one or more of [the values listed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Oops.. didn't quite read you post right.. i have the same behaviour - last value is always zero.. Sorry, voted for deletion of my answer.. :)

Comment: The function returns garbage when the window doesn't have a title bar.  If it has one then the close button is always visible so 0 is a correct value.

Comment: @HansPassant Oh. Well, that explains that. Thanks!